# pairedrdd: how to calculate all pairwise differences (in values) efficiently

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> ```
> rdd1 key is (user_id, inc_id)
> ```
>
> user_id, inc_id, visit_date1 visit_date2 visit_date3 visit_date4
>
> rdd2  key is also (user_id, inc_id) 
>   user_id, inc_id, purchase_date1 purchase_date2 purchase_date3 purchase_date4

The dates are sorted in the chronological manner (visit_date1 occurs before visit_date 2)

> Here is what I want to calculate the first occurrence of this
>   condition for each  (user_id, inc_id) combination the earliest time
>   when the difference between (visit_date and purchase_date) is less
>   than 24 hours.   I want to do this is a very efficient manner since I
>   have tens of millions of (user_id, inc_id) pairs and
>   hundreds/thousands of entries per (user_id, inc_id) pair.
>
> Here is some sample data:
>
> rdd1

```
(100, 1) 2015-01-12 06:32:00.0    2015-02-14 18:32:20.0   2015-03-18 11:18:25.0    2015-04-28 10:18:24.0
```

> rdd2

```
(100, 1) 2014-12-18 16:32:00.0    2015-01-10  8:32:20.0   2015-03-18 20:18:25.0   2015-04-28 11:28:42.0
```

> In this case both  (2015-03-18 11:18:25.0   2015-03-18 20:18:25.0) and
>   (2015-04-28  10:18:24.0  2015-04-28 11:28:42.0) satisfy the within 24
>   hr condition. However, since 2015-03-18 11:18:25.0 occurs before
>   2015-04-28  10:18:24.0 I would like (2015-03-18 11:18:25.0
>   2015-03-18 20:18:25.0) to be selected as the result.

Comment: and what have you tried so far ? can you also give an example input and output ?

Comment: All I could think of was computing all the pairwise date differences and then testing if any of those values satisfy the condition. I think this may be quite inefficient.

Comment: ok. can you review your question please ? it's not clear anymore what you want a share some code too. :)

Comment: I want to first have some idea about how to achieve this efficiently and then I will code it up. I will be happy to share the code when I get ti working.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand since you're not giving data types or code sample, you'd need to foldbykey your RDD and check the difference between accumulator and current value is less than 24 hours